# Can IdentityServer4 act as an Active Directory provider?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, identityserver4

Let's say I have an ASP.NET Core website which uses IdentityServer4 for authentication. I am using AspNetCore.Identity for user and role management which allows me to save the website users into SQL database. The users of the website are all employees of a specific department in some company. In their office they all have windows computers and personal accounts with username and password, so they can log in to their work computers.

What I want to do is turn my IdentityServer web app into Active Directory provider and connect it with their local windows computer, so that they can log in to their windows machines with the credentials that they have on the IdentityServer website.

**Can I use IdentityServer for this scenario and how?**

Comment: I don't think this is a possible scenario. But log in to your webapp using identityserver external provider(configured with their active directory through ADFS or Azure AD) is  the common scenario.

Comment: I am aware of that common scenario but as I stated I have the opposite scenario. It looks like it is not possible to do it as I have imagined in any easy way. I think I will integrate Azure AD B2C (by using their API) within my IdentityServer. So whenever users signs up on my web app through IdentityServer I will call the Azure AD B2C api to create an account there for the new user. This way I can connect that Azure AD with the workspace windows machines.

Comment: Ok, I'm just curious why users need to log into their workstation with identityserver credentials?

Comment: That's part of a specific business need for the web application.